# how to write different information to two different files using same logger of log4j?

Tags: java, logging, file, log4j

I'd like to write to two different files using my logger, which is declared like this:

```
public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Adapt.class);
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

the file log4j contains:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FA

#File Appender
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FA.File=temp.ppr
log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.append=false
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n
```

Is it possible at all to use logger to write different text to two different files easily?

If not, is there a way to do that with two loggers? (I tried that and got problems because of the function configure which is static.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Just define a second logger variable:

```
Logger otherLogger = Logger.getLogger("OTHER_LOGGER");
```

define a configuration for it (notice the log4j.**logger**.OTHER_LOGGER syntax cf. log4j.rootLogger, as pointed out by [user623395](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707847/how-to-write-different-information-to-two-different-files-using-same-logger-of-l/5043359#5043359) and [venkatesh Dodla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707847/how-to-write-different-information-to-two-different-files-using-same-logger-of-l/5316717#5316717)):

```
log4j.logger.OTHER_LOGGER=DEBUG, OtherAppender

log4j.additivity.OTHER_LOGGER = false

#File Appender
log4j.appender.OtherAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.OtherAppender.File=temp2.ppr
log4j.appender.OtherAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.OtherAppender.append=false
log4j.appender.OtherAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n
```

and log your different text as usual:

```
logger.debug("My normal log");
otherLogger.info("My special text");
```

Comment: The configuration is my problem , how do i connect it to this specific logger? PropertyConfigurator.configure get only the path of the property file , and not the logger object

Comment: Put it all in the same file. Both the log4j.rootLogger and the log4j.OTHER_LOGGER lines.

Comment: well that doesnt work , i tried doing logger.info("1");  otherLogger.info("2"); and what i got is that temp2.ppr file wasnt created, and temp.ppr had the text 12... what to do ?

Comment: Did you configure the appenders correctly? Do both loggers point to a different appender?

Comment: i just added your lines into the file , and also the decleration of otherLogger , just as you wrote it .  My code is the same as i wrote on the question.

Comment: Just added a line about additivity to my answer. This will prevent the content of otherLogger to be visible to the rootLogger.

Answer (score 2):

To create temp2.ppr, change from

```
log4j.OTHER_LOGGER=DEBUG, OtherAppender
```

to

```
log4j.**logger**.OTHER_LOGGER=DEBUG, OtherAppender
```

Answer (score 2):

it worked for me.
My Log file:

```
# log4j.properties
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,hfis,stdout
#For second log
log4j.logger.OTHER_LOGGER=DEBUG, OtherAppender
log4j.additivity.OTHER_LOGGER = false 

#File Appender 
log4j.appender.OtherAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender 
log4j.appender.OtherAppender.File=C:\\Legacy.log
log4j.appender.OtherAppender.ImmediateFlush=true 
log4j.appender.OtherAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.OtherAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n 

log4j.rootCategory=ERROR
log4j.rootLogger.additivity=false

log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.hfis=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.hfis.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.hfis.file=C:\\hfis.log 
log4j.appender.hfis.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.hfis.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.hfis.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hfis.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
# R is the RollingFileAppender that outputs to a rolling log
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG

# Define a pattern layout for the file.
log4j.appender.mystdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mystdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p: %m%n<br>
```

and my log variables are

```
final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("hfis");
final static Logger log2 = Logger.getLogger("OTHER_LOGGER");
```