# Write log to standard output or file in log4j java

Tags: java, log4j

I want to write log4j log to standard output or to a file according to a variable. If a variable writeLogToFile is set, the log should be written to a file, otherwise to standard output.

I have tried with the following code, but log is written to both file as well as standard output.

```
public class LTE {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LTE.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*some code which sets variables writeLogToFile and logFile*/

        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        if(writeLogToFile) {
            FileAppender fappender = new FileAppender(new PatternLayout("%-6p [%t] (%F:%L) %m%n"), logFile);
            logger.addAppender(fappender);
        }

        /*some code which uses info and debug methods to write log*/
    }
}
```

This works when I want log to be written to standard output as by default log is written to standard ouptput. But this fails when I want to write log to a file. Log is written to both standard output as well as to a file.

So, I tried following code, but this also did not work.

```
public class LTE {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LTE.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*some code which sets variables writeLogToFile and logFile*/

        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        if(writeLogToFile) {
            FileAppender fappender = new FileAppender(new PatternLayout("%-6p [%t] (%F:%L) %m%n"), logFile);
            logger.addAppender(fappender);
            Properties logProperties = new Properties();
            logProperties.setProperty("log4j.additivity.notRootLogger", "false");
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(logProperties);
        }

        /*some code which uses info and debug methods to write log*/
    }
}
```

I also tried following

```
public class LTE {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LTE.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*some code which sets variables writeLogToFile and logFile*/

        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        if(writeLogToFile) {
            FileAppender fappender = new FileAppender(new PatternLayout("%-6p [%t] (%F:%L) %m%n"), logFile);
            logger.addAppender(fappender);
        }
        else {
            ConsoleAppender cappender = new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout("%-6p [%t] (%F:%L) %m%n"), "System.out");
            logger.addAppender(cappender);
        }

        /*some code which uses info and debug methods to write log*/
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me in solving this problem?

[EDIT]

OK. I think I solved the problem. I added a line `logger.setAdditivity(false);` in my code like this

```
public class LTE {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LTE.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*some code which sets variables writeLogToFile and logFile*/

        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        if(writeLogToFile) {
            FileAppender fappender = new FileAppender(new PatternLayout("%-6p [%t] (%F:%L) %m%n"), logFile);
            logger.addAppender(fappender);
            logger.setAdditivity(false);    //added line here
        }

        /*some code which uses info and debug methods to write log*/
    }
}
```

Now it is working properly. If `writeLogToFile=true` then log is written to standard output, otherwise it is written to file.

Comment: Paste your log4j configuration file

Comment: I have pasted configuration file in the reply to Paul's answer. By the way, I have found the solution and I have edited my original post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have configured your logger to already contain a ConsoleAppender? You should try to show all Appenders: try to use Logger.getAllAppenders() and show their classes.

You could also look in your log4j.properties and log4j.xml files.

Comment: If I use logger.getAllAppenders(), then it shows only one appender which is a FileAppender. If I use Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders(), then it shows only one appender which is a ConsoleAppender.

Comment: Anyways, I found the solution which I have written as an edit in my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this example:
[how to write different information to two different files using same logger of log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707847/how-to-write-different-information-to-two-different-files-using-same-logger-of-l)

And then in your program you decide which logger to use.

```
if(writeLogToFile)
   logger.debug("My normal log");
else
   otherLogger.info("My special text");
```