# Log into different files with the same logger with Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have a Class "Example.class". I get my Logger with:

```
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Example.class);
```

My log4j.properties looks like:

```
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=log.txt

    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1024KB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5

    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

My Class is logging via log.info(..), log.debug(..) and so on into the file **log.txt**.

Now i want to have a different logger for the same class e.g.:

```
    private final Logger differentLogger = Logger.getLogger(Example.class);
```

and this logger should log into a different file for example

```
    differentLogger.info("Hello World");
    //writes 'Hello World' into differentLogFile.txt
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Answer !

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707847/how-to-write-different-information-to-two-different-files-using-same-logger-of-l

Answer (score 1):

No, the category identifies the logger.

That said, you are not forced to use the class as the category. You could use in the same class:

```
private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Example.class);

private final Logger differentLogger = Logger.getLogger(mylogs.different);
```

After that, in the configuration file you can define several appenders and assign each category to a different appender.

Comment: I guess, i don't understand the mapping from the configured appender in the configuration file and the instantiation in my java code. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Logger.getLogger(Example.class)` twice will return the same or undistinguishable instances of `Logger`. This means Log4J cannot make any distinction between them and they will always land up in the same file.

The solution is obvious: use a different logger!

```
Logger differentLogger = Logger.getLogger("differentLogger");
```

And configure `log4j.xml` to use different appender for `differentLogger`.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example for the configuration file?